# Max retries exceeded with URL Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i'm looking to traverse a URL array and open different URL's for web scraping with Selenium. The problem is, as soon as I hit the second browser.get(url), I get a 'Max retries exceeded with URL' and 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'.

EDIT: Added the rest of the code, although it's just BeautifulSoup stuff.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json

chrome_options = Options()  
chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/andre/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
urlArr = ['https://link1', 'https://link2', '...']

for url in urlArr:
   with chromedriver as browser:
      browser.get(url)
      time.sleep(5)
      # Click a button
      chromedriver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[7].click()

      chromedriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
      time.sleep(2)
      for i in range (0, 2):
         chromedriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
         time.sleep(5)

      html = browser.page_source
      page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
      boxes = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "rpBJOHq2PR60pnwJlUyP0"})
      videos = page_soup.findAll("video", {"class": "_1EQJpXY7ExS04odI1YBBlj"})
```

The other posts on here say this happens when you use too many pages at once and the server shuts me out, but that's not my issue. Whenever I call browser.get(url) more than once, the error above happens.

Whats going on? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the problem. You have to recreate the webdriver again.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json


urlArr = ['https://link1', 'https://link2', '...']

for url in urlArr:
   chrome_options = Options()  
   chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/andre/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
   with chromedriver as browser:
      browser.get(url)
      time.sleep(5)
      # Click a button
      chromedriver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[7].click()

      chromedriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
      time.sleep(2)
      for i in range (0, 2):
         chromedriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
         time.sleep(5)

      html = browser.page_source
      page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
      boxes = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "rpBJOHq2PR60pnwJlUyP0"})
      videos = page_soup.findAll("video", {"class": "_1EQJpXY7ExS04odI1YBBlj"})
```

Comment: You didn't solve anything. Now you're opening a new browser for each url (and not closing them)

Comment: @pguardiario the "with" statement block means that it gets closed at the end.