# MaxRetryError while web scraping workaround - Python, Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am having some really hard times trying to figure out how to webscrape  making multiple requests to the same website. I have to web scrape 3000 products from a website. That implies making various requests to that server (for example searching the product, clicking on it, going back to the home page) 3000 times.
I state that I am using Selenium. If I only launch one instance of my Firefox webdriver I don't get a MaxRetryError, but as the search goes on my webdriver gets slower and slower, and when the program reaches about half of the searches it stops responding. I looked it up on some forums and I found out it does so for some browser memory issues. So I tried quitting and reinstantiating the webdriver every n seconds (I tried with 100, 200 and 300 secs), but when I do so I get that MaxRetryError because of the too many requests to that url using the same session.
I then tried making the program sleep for a minute when the exception occurs but that hasn't worked (I am only able to make another search and then an exception is again thrown, and so on).
I am wondering if there is any workaround for these kind of issue.
It might be using another library, a way for changing IP or session dynamically or something like that.
P.S. I would rather keep working with selenium if possible.

Comment: Has the problem been solved? Do let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

This error is normally raised if the server determines a high request rate from your client.

As you mentioned, the server bans your `IP` from making further requests so you can get around that by using some available technologies. Look into `Zalenium` and also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133200/scraping-in-python-preventing-ip-ban) for some other possible ways.

Another possible (but tedious) way is to use a number of browser instances to make the call, for example, an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58968304/6505847) illustrates that.

```
urlArr = ['https://link1', 'https://link2', '...']

for url in urlArr:
   chrome_options = Options()  
   chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/andre/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
   with chromedriver as browser:
      browser.get(url)
      # your task
      chromedriver.close() # will close only the current chrome window.

browser.quit() # should close all of the open windows,
```